# Get erros block SQL (SQL Server) in ZF2 + Doctrine 2

Tags: php, sql-server, zend-framework2, doctrine

I can't catch error in doctrine 2 + zf2 in sql block.

My environment is ZF2 + Doctrine 2.

Code:

```
public function test() {
    $connection = $this->_em->getConnection();
    $sql = "DECLARE @Test AS dbo.DataTempTransactions
            INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('015.004.000',100,'015A')
            DECLARE @DATE datetime
            SET @DATE = GETDATE()
            EXEC ONCode.dbo.TmSp_Exit @Test, @mnfdate = @DATE
            SELECT * FROM ONTest.dbo.OBTN";
    $stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
    return $stmt->execute();
}
```

I am using a table valued parameter in the sql block (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx), I dont know if influence something.

When I run this code in the zf2 app it not appear the error but in the Visual Studio the same sql block has an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a user-defined type, it is local to a single database. Therefore, a user-defined type defined in one database cannot be used in a column definition of another database. However, if the same user-defined type is registered and can be accessed in two databases, you can convert a user-defined type value from one database for use in another database. This ability is useful when you want to do the following:

- Call a stored procedure that is defined in a different database.
- Query over tables that are defined in two different databases.
- Select data from a database and insert it into another.

Reference: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178069(v=sql.105).aspx